# Reason for creating a package per dimension or fact table

Tags: ssis

I have subscribed to plural sight as recommended by a user from stack flow. On the SSIS training the trainer mentioned to create a package per dimensional/fact table.  But didn't give any reason as to why.  In my simple little mind,  it just seems to make sense to do as much possibly in one package rather than have a package per table or fact.  What is the reason behind that if anyone care to enlighten me please :)

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that it gives you more granular control.   If you have a scenario one day where you only want to update one table without updating all of them, you have that ability.

If you also want the ability to do all your tables in one package, you can always create a parent package that calls all of the child packages and execute that.